# hide element when radio is checked css only

Tags: html, css

The span elements in this picture are from the mdn docs on how to hide an element using css only. It works as expected. Clicking showMe/hideMe does whats expected.

How come when I try to do the same when my radio element is checked, nothing happens? Here is the relevant code:

```
   <!-- html -->
    <div>
      <input class="firstClass" type="radio" id="firstId">
      <label for="firstId">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable">
      <label for="secondId">Type of disability</label>
      <input type="text" id="secondId">
    </div>


    /* css */
    .expandable {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .firstClass:checked ~ .expandable {
      display: block;
    }
```

[image: im stuck]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 .expandable {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .firstClass:checked ~ .expandable {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <input class="firstClass" type="checkbox" id="firstId">
      <label for="firstId">Yes</label>
   
    <div class="expandable">
      <label for="secondId">Type of disability</label>
      <input type="text" id="secondId">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I wanted to use the radio element for my form

Comment: so change button type  radio....

Comment: Aw yeah. Thanks so much! I really tried to google the answer. i gave you an upvote but someone else gave you a downvote so.. at least its not negative.